# Encountered error Webdevelopment in bootstrap using npm

Tags: javascript, css, npm, webpack

I was following freeCodeCamp video tutorial on web development
https://youtu.be/RyTRgQ7k6QE

I followed it completely but can't seem to overcome this error:

```
PS C:\Admin-Dashboard> npx webpack --config webpack.config.js
[webpack-cli] Compilation finished
assets by status 170 KiB [cached] 1 asset
runtime modules 1.13 KiB 5 modules
orphan modules 1 bytes [orphan] 1 module
cacheable modules 508 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 508 KiB
    ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js 140 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js 281 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/popper.js/dist/esm/popper.js 86.4 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./src/ 107 bytes
    ./src/js/app.js 68 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./src/sass/main.scss 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/sass/main.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. PostCSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'plugins'. These properties are valid:
   object { postcssOptions?, execute?, sourceMap? }
    at validate (C:\Admin-Dashboard\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:104:11)
    at Object.loader (C:\Admin-Dashboard\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:43:29)
    at processResult (C:\Admin-Dashboard\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:576:19)
    at C:\Admin-Dashboard\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:669:5
    at C:\Admin-Dashboard\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:397:11
    at C:\Admin-Dashboard\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:252:18
 @ ./src/js/app.js 2:0-27

1 ERROR in child compilations
webpack 5.0.0 compiled with 2 errors in 7390 ms
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: *PostCSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'plugins'*  That is your error. Your `postcss-loader` is configured wrong. Replace your current `postcss-loader` config with the one from their [docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/postcss-loader)

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling existing postcss-loader and downgrade to 3.0.0

npm uninstall postcss-loader

npm install postcss-loader@3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Yay! the webpack compiled successfully!
Downgrading the postcss-loader created more dependency compatibility errors.

Reyno correctly pointed the postcss-loader didn't configured properly, I configured the postcss-loader from this link:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/postcss-loader
which reyno has commented in his answer.
Thank you guys for your help!